# What is the image of $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ $f(x, y) = (x^2-y^2, 2xy)$ with $x>0$?

Tags: calculus

What I have now:

Let $x=r\cos\theta, y=r\sin\theta$, with $r>0, -\dfrac{\pi}{2}<\theta <\dfrac{\pi}{2}$, and then$$f(x, y)=(r^2{\cos\theta}^2- r^2{\sin\theta}^2, 2\cos\theta \sin\theta)=(r^2\cos2\theta, r^2\sin2\theta)$$
I am not sure where to go beyond those steps. It seems that it should be circles with radius $r^2$, and centred at $(0,0)$. Any help, thanks ahead!

Comment: If you know complex numbers, then identify $(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2$ with $x+y\text{i}\in\mathbb{C}$.  Then, $f(z)=z^2$ for all $z\in\mathbb{C}$.  Consequently, the image of the half plane $\big\{z\in\mathbb{C}\,\big|\,\text{Re}(z)>0\big\}$ is $\mathbb{C}\setminus\mathbb{R}_{\leq 0}$.

Comment: @Batominovski I don't know complex number. Is the image the whole plane of $R^2$?

Comment: No, it is not.  The negative real axis and the origin are not in the image.

Comment: @Batominovski So the image is the whole plane except for origin and negative real axis? Why they're not in the image?

Comment: Image is the half plane $\big\{z\in\mathbb{C}\,\big|\,\text{Re}(z)>0\big\}$ because of what you have written in the question.($x\gt 0$)

Answer (score 2):

What you have done is fine. You have shown image is the set $$\{(r^2\cos 2\theta,r^2\sin2\theta)\,|\, r >0, -\pi/2 < \theta < \pi/2\} = \{(r^2\cos \phi,r^2\sin\phi)\,|\, r >0, -\pi < \phi < \pi\}.$$

The image, however, can be simplified.

The image is `most' of $\mathbb{R}^2$ since $\mathbb{R}^2 = \{(r\cos \phi,r\sin\phi)\,|\, r \geq 0, -\pi \leq \phi < \pi\}$. Now ask yourself, what elements are in $\mathbb{R}^2$ that aren't in the image.

Comment: Only the origin isn't in the image, right ??@Timothy_Hedgeworth

Comment: Not quite, since setting $\theta = -\pi$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ gives the set $\{(-r,0)\,|\,r\geq 0\}$ and this is not in the image!

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked the negative part.